# Playing music in java on threads

Tags: java, multithreading, media-player, media

I am currently creating virtual drum kit. Kinect is recording my moves and when I hit the virtual drum the program needs to play the sound of this drum. Currently my code to play music looks like that:

```
void playInstrumentSound(InstrumentModel instrument) {
    if (instrument.getMedia() != null) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                instrument.setPlaying(true);
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(instrument.getMedia());
                player.setVolume(1);
                player.play();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(properties.getSleepLength());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                instrument.setPlaying(false);
                player.dispose();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

InstrumentModel is my class that contains Media object that is initialized by using pathToSound which is path to .wav file in resources folder:

```
if (this.pathToSound != null) {
    media = new Media(new File(this.pathToSound).toURI().toString());
}
```

Right now this code doesn't reach my expectations, because if I hit a drum then I can't hit it again for the properties.getSleepLength() value of time (now it is about 200ms). If I don`t make Thread sleep then I don't hear full sound.

For example, if the .wav file duration is 300ms and I make Thread.sleep(300) inside playInstrumentSound() method, then I can hear full sound but I can't play different sound for this 300ms. But if I make Thread.sleep(50) then I can hit it again almost instantly but I hear only 50ms of the .wav file.

I would like to be able to hit the drum almost instantly but also hear full sound of it. How can I reach that? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I just got an idea to change order inside playInstrumentSoundMethod:

```
void playInstrumentSound(InstrumentModel instrument) {
    if (instrument.getMedia() != null) {
        instrument.setPlaying(true);
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(instrument.getMedia());
        player.setVolume(1);
        player.play();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                instrument.setPlaying(false);
            }
        }.start();
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                player.dispose();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Now it should turn the sound off after 250ms and changes isPlaying flag after 50ms (if isPlaying flag is true then you can't hit a drum again). You think that it might work?

Comment: can you please add your MediaPlayer class?

Comment: Media player is a class from javafx.scene.media package. I found it when I was looking for a library that will let me play sound in Java. If there is better alternative then feel free to tell me :)

Comment: Maybe the Java Sound API (never used that myself, but there is a downloadable example)
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html

Comment: Looks nice, I'll try that tomorrow, thanks.